# VS Code suppress terminal output

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've created a custom task that opens `Google-Chrome` with the currently opened file. This works great, but I can't seem to find a way to suppress the output in the terminal.

Trying the [suggestion on the site](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) doesn't help either.

**Tasks.json**

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "Open in browser",
            "command": "google-chrome",
            "type": "process",
            "args": ["${file}"],
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "never",
                "echo": false
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

The output is always visible in the Terminal:

[image]

Is there a way to have no output at all?